# Understand the design decision of ownership in Rust

Tags: rust, ownership

I am trying to understand the usage of ownership in Rust.

So from what I can understand, ownership is a runtime mechanism which enforces the programmers to think further and prevent some unexpected and unnoticed read-write hazards or so.

But my question is that, this seems could be figured out by static analysis during compilation, why leave it to the runtime?

Also, could anyone share some experiences on using it during more real-world programming? I am a bit hesitant about using this, largely.

Comment: Rust ownership works at compile time

Comment: As the answer below suggests, the [book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html) covers this particular subject pretty well. It is done at compile time, although it can be made into a run-time construct with some smart pointer types such (e.g. [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/index.html)). Your second question is too broad and not appropriate for the site. The [official website](https://www.rust-lang.org/) contains a few experiences from companies who started using Rust. You can also find so many others around the web in the form of blog posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ownership in Rust is done at [compile-time](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html). You can see this as static analyzing at compile-time. It can be your best friend, but also your worst enemy. To develop with Rust, one needs patience. But you are also going to become a better programmer, because you are going to start thinking about dangling references, scopes, and memory allocations in general.